# Is there any difference in the memory layout of Windows and Linux OS?

Tags: c, windows, linux, memory, layout

When I run the code written below on windows and on Linux, I get different output for the two.

I am using gcc for both. When I run it on windows, I get "Seek" as output whereas running it on Linux, I am getting "Hide" as the output. Is there any difference in the memory layout of Windows and Linux, or is there something else which causes the output to differ?

```
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    int *b=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(&a>b)
        printf("Hide");
    else
        printf("Seek");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably there is a difference. But does it matter?

Comment: Are you trying to detect stack or heap allocation? You can't really do that portably. In a multithreaded program you will have several stacks, just to add to the confusion.

Comment: This is the prototypical implementation detail. Your code should never ever care about memory layout—if it does, you've already made a huge mistake.

Comment: Side note: Write `type *name = malloc(count * sizeof(*name));`, instead of `type *name = (type *)malloc(count * sizeof(type));`. This way, you won't keep repeating the `type`.

Comment: @Shahbaz I suspect a C++ compiler is involved, in which case the extra cast is needed.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan, the `sizeof(*name)` is still applicable. Besides, the question is tagged [Tag:C].

Comment: @Shahbaz I'm aware. My point still stands.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, windows and linux lay out their memory differently. Some examples are [here](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory). For example, windows typically splits your memory evenly (in 32-bit) between kernel and user space, while linux is 3/1 user/kernel.

The compiler can also lay out the memory as it sees fit, within the limits of the spec. This means that the llvm compiler, gcc, and ever different versions of these can have different output.

Optimizations can also change layout, and even remove some variables that aren't strictly needed.

Also, even if memory was allocated low to high, after some other memory was freed a new allocation could come from the previously used area and be low again.

Short answer: expecting memory layout/location between unrelated variables is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `malloc` is unspecified (could be anything). In other words, in no part of the standard does it guarantee predictability of the return value. This is part of the C language standard rather than platform specific and is not really related to memory layout. From the C99 standard:

> **7.20.3 Memory management functions**
>
> **1 The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to the calloc, malloc, and
>   realloc functions is unspeciﬁed**. The pointer returned if the
>   allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to
>   a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object
>   or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is
>   explicitly deallocated). The lifetime of an allocated object extends
>   from the allocation until the deallocation. Each such allocation shall
>   yield a pointer to an object disjoint from any other object. The
>   pointer returned points to the start (lowest byte address) of the
>   allocated space. If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is
>   returned. If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
>   implementation deﬁned: either a null pointer is returned, or the
>   behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
>   returned pointer shall not be used to access an object

What you have come across is implementation-defined behaviour which is not guaranteed to hold in the future. In fact, it is not even guaranteed to hold in current versions of Windows/Linux.

Comment: Standardese has nothing to do with his question.

Comment: @akappa: Sure it does. He is asking the reason behind the behaviour that he has noticed. I am simply stating that such behaviour is implementation-defined and not related to what he thinks it is related to. I then back this up by quoting the part of the standard relating to how the return value is defined. If he starts to rely on such behaviour, it is inherently a huge step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Why do you assume this is code meant for production? Maybe it is just exploring up something, and maybe he's wondering where stack and heap are allocated to. The fact that this is implementation-specific says nothing about those intellectual curiosities, which seems to be the point of his question.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you very often have [address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (which might also happen on Windows). So the compare could perhaps gives different results from one run to another (in particular if your code was inside some shared library, which gets randomly `mmap`-ed).

And to understand the memory map, you could display `/proc/self/maps` by adding the following Linux specific code:

```
{
   char linbuf[128];
   FILE* mapfil=("/proc/self/maps");
   if (!mapfil) 
     perror("/proc/self/maps"), exit(1);
   while (!feof (mapfil)) {
     memset(linbuf, sizeof(linbuf), 0);
     fgets(linbuf, sizeof(linbuf), mapfil);
     fputs(linbuf, stdout);
   };
   fclose(mapfil), fflush(NULL);
}
```

(put that code after your `malloc`, and add a `\n` to every `printf` format string without it).

You could also use the `pmap` utility if you have the process id of your program.