# Buffer Overflow Discrepancy: Works on Linux VM but Fails on Windows Machine when Implementing Buffer Overflow Example

Tags: c, linux, windows, buffer-overflow

I am trying to learn about buffer overflows from this book I am reading called "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation" by Jon Erickson. Essentially I am passing more bytes in my command line argument than the char array can store causing a buffer overflow. My objective is to write the exact bytes, `0xdeadbeef`, into the value variable. This code works on my Linux VM but not on my Windows machine... why is this?

##### overflow_example.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];

    strcpy(buffer_one, "one");
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two");

    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n",&value, value, value);

    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]);

    printf("[AFTER] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
    return 0;
}
```

On my Windows x86_64 machine I am only able to write `0x0000beef` to the value variable and whenever I try to write something like `0xdeadbeef` I get a value that I don't really understand. I calculated the distance between `buffer_two`(0061FF0C) and `value`(0061FF1C) to be 16 bytes hence why I fill the first 16 bytes with the char `A`.

##### beef example from Windows 10 x86_64 machine

```
$ ./overflow_example.exe `perl -e 'print "\x41"x16 . "\xEF\xBE"'`
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0061FF0C and contains 'two'
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0061FF14 and contains 'one'
[BEFORE] value is at 0061FF1C and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 18 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0061FF0C and contains 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA∩╛'
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0061FF14 and contains 'AAAAAAAA∩╛'
[AFTER] value is at 0061FF1C and is 48879 (0x0000beef)
```

##### deadbeef example from Windows 10 x86_64 machine

```
$ ./overflow_example.exe `perl -e 'print "\x41"x16 . "\xEF\xBE\xAD\xDE"'`
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0061FF0C and contains 'two'
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0061FF14 and contains 'one'
[BEFORE] value is at 0061FF1C and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 18 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0061FF0C and contains 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA?▐'
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0061FF14 and contains 'AAAAAAAA?▐'
[AFTER] value is at 0061FF1C and is 56895 (0x0000de3f)
```

However when I try to run the same code on my KALI VM it seems to work. Why is this the case?

##### QEMU KALI-Linux VM on same machine

```
$ ./overflow_example.exe `perl -e 'print "\x41"x16 . "\xEF\xBE\xAD\xDE"'`
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0x7ffedc85505c and contains 'two'
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0x7ffedc855064 and contains 'one'
[BEFORE] value is at 7ffedc85506c and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 18 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0x7ffedc85505c and contains 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA?▐'
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0x7ffedc855064 and contains 'AAAAAAAA?▐'
[AFTER] value is at 0x7ffedc85506c and is -559038737 (0xdeadbeef)
```

Comment: Most probably you have to disable ```Buffer Security Check``` when you build the executable image for your windows. On visual studio this is located at: ```Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Buffer Security Check```

Comment: Also might be helpful:  [Is there any difference in the memory layout of Windows and Linux OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687516/is-there-any-difference-in-the-memory-layout-of-windows-and-linux-os)